# How can I use an aggregate function in my select while using group by

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have 3 table named `Sale`, `SaleStatus`, `SaleStatusType`. The table structure is like below

```
Sale Status:
   SaleStatusID
   SaleStatusTypeID
   CreateDate
   SaleID
SaleStatusType:
   SaleStatusTypeID
   SaleStatusTypeName
Sale:
   SaleID
   <other sale info>
```

There can be multiple SaleStatus for one SaleID.
Now if I want to select each `saleID` and its latest `SaleStatus` information added to my database based on `CreateDate` (`DATETIME` type), what should I do?
I've written something like the following which results in error

```
SELECT SST.SaleStatusType, SS.SaleStatusTypeID, SS.SaleID
FROM SaleStatusType AS SST
   INNER JOIN SaleStatus AS SS 
      ON SS.SaleStatusTypeID = SST.SaleStatusTypeID
GROUP BY S.SaleID
HAVING SS.CreateDate = MAX(SS.CreateDate)
```

Comment: your group by has the wrong alias, it should be `SS`, but it will still error because you are selecting columns outside of the group by without a `max()` or `min()`. Instead you should do a partition over `SS.CreateDate` with a where clause. https://www.sqlshack.com/sql-partition-by-clause-overview/

Comment: Your approach is not the best way to handle this kind of thing. Try [this approach](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group) instead.

Comment: Thanks for your answers.  Yeah this new approach seems to be working. I'm kinda new to writing raw sql these little tips help alot